# Install qt-mobility through buildroot

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, buildroot

I'm currently porting a project on a SAMA5d2 based board with a custom Linux, this project is a .pro project so I need to use Qt for compiling it.

The project is the following one : [Buteo-mtp](https://github.com/hufman/buteo-mtp)

Here is my Config.in file

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_BUTEO_MTP
    bool "Buteo MTP project"
    help
        buteo-mtp is a project presenting the board as a MTP device. 

    https://github.com/hufman/buteo-mtp
```

Here is my .mk file

```
##############################################################################    ##
#
# buteo-mtp project for Base boards
#
################################################################################
BUTEO_MTP_SITE_METHOD = git
BUTEO_MTP_SITE = https://github.com/hufman/buteo-mtp
BUTEO_MTP_VERSION = 0.1.2

define BUTEO_MTP_CONFIGURE_CMDS
    $(HOST_DIR)/usr/bin/qmake -o $(@D)/Makefile $(@D)/libmeegomtp.pro
endef

define BUTEO_MTP_BUILD_CMDS
    make -C $(@D)
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

---

I first tried with buildroot integrated last Qt5 version (currently 5.8). However even if Makefile generation from .pro worked, compilation failed with the following error :

```
$ make
>>> buteo-mtp 0.1.2 Downloading
Doing shallow clone
Clonage dans 'buteo-mtp-0.1.2'...
remote: Counting objects: 127, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (107/107), done.
remote: Total 127 (delta 24), reused 85 (delta 15), pack-reused 0
Réception d'objets: 100% (127/127), 220.43 KiB | 51.00 KiB/s, fait.
Résolution des deltas: 100% (24/24), fait.
Note : extraction de '56bfa87a9bf32997215583d28c7b97d57415724c'.
>>> buteo-mtp 0.1.2 Extracting
gzip -d -c <BR_path>/dl/buteo-mtp-0.1.2.tar.gz | tar --strip-components=1 -C <BR_path>/output/build/buteo-mtp-0.1.2   -xf -
>>> buteo-mtp 0.1.2 Patching
>>> buteo-mtp 0.1.2 Configuring
<BR_path>/output/host/usr/bin/qmake -o <BR_path>/output/build/buteo-mtp-0.1.2/Makefile <BR_path>/output/build/buteo-mtp-0.1.2/libmeegomtp.pro
>>> buteo-mtp 0.1.2 Building
make -C <BR_path>/output/build/buteo-mtp-0.1.2
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « <BR_path>/output/build/buteo-mtp-0.1.2 »
cd mts/ && ( test -e Makefile || <BR_path>/output/host/usr/bin/qmake -o Makefile <BR_path>/output/build/buteo-mtp-0.1.2/mts/mts.pro ) && make -f Makefile 
Project WARNING: Cross compiling without sysroot. Disabling pkg-config.
Project WARNING: Cross compiling without sysroot. Disabling pkg-config.
sh: 1: --exists: not found
Project ERROR: Qt5SystemInfo development package not found
Makefile:50 : la recette pour la cible « sub-mts-make_first » a échouée
make[1]: *** [sub-mts-make_first] Erreur 3
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « <BR_path>/output/build/buteo-mtp-0.1.2 »
package/pkg-generic.mk:216 : la recette pour la cible « <BR_path>/output/build/buteo-mtp-0.1.2/.stamp_built » a échouée
make: *** [<BR_path>/output/build/buteo-mtp-0.1.2/.stamp_built] Erreur 2
```

After some researchs I found that QtSystemInfo is a development package contained in qt-mobility. However I'm not able to find a buildroot package containing Qt5SystemInfo.

However I found a buildroot configuration for qt-mobility which depends on Qt4 at https://github.com/virt2real/dm36x-buildroot/tree/master/package/qt-mobility

So after building Qt4.8 through buildroot I added the qt-mobility package and I enabled SystemInfo module. However nothing is built or downloaded after running make.
In fact the referenced site for sources doesn't exist anymore. (like the half of the given links in Qt documentation....)

```
QT_MOBILITY_VERSION = 1.2.0
QT_MOBILITY_SOURCE  = v$(QT_MOBILITY_VERSION)
QT_MOBILITY_SITE    = http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-mobility/qt-mobility/archive-tarball
QT_MOBILITY_DEPENDENCIES = qt
QT_MOBILITY_INSTALL_STAGING = YES
```

Does someone know where I could find a tar archive of qt-mobility sources and moreover on a website which will keep this for long time support ?

I don't have any experience with Qt yet but it seems to me that it's **very very messy** and I don't find so much informations. Moreover many documentation I found is deprecated or given links are dead.

Also does qt-mobility exists with Qt5 or has been replaced by another module?

Answer (score 3):

From a quick look, it seems like `Qt5SystemInfo` is not part of Qt5 itself, but rather an extension specific to the Mer/SailfishOS project.

I would suggest that you use a more recent version of buteo-mtp, since references to Qt5SystemInfo have been removed in commit 1ccd51eee9442210f058d3054cb83d811ef863a5, which is after the 0.1.2 release you're using.

Comment: Can you explain how you saw that? The last release/tag I see is v0.1.2 released on 8 Jul 2013. <br/>
How do you see references to Qt5SystemInfo have been removed ?